# Pandas grouping on a dictionary column with None values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with two columns. A column `ID` that contains a dict that identifies each data and a column `latency` which is a float.

In this DataFrame I have some values for which the ID will be a None (I can change to another 'default' value if needed) with a latency of None (which become NaN)

Here is an example :

```
                                ID  latency
0  {u'ID': u'AAA', u'subID': u'0'}    126.0
1  {u'ID': u'AAA', u'subID': u'0'}     70.0
2  {u'ID': u'BBB', u'subID': u'0'}     50.0
3  {u'ID': u'BBB', u'subID': u'0'}     20.0
4  {u'ID': u'BBB', u'subID': u'1'}    200.0
5                             None      NaN
```

I want to add a new column `isMinimalLatency` with value 1 if this row have the minimal latency value for the ID and 0 else.

Here is an example of output :

```
                                ID  latency  isMinimalLatency
0  {u'ID': u'AAA', u'subID': u'0'}    126.0                 0
1  {u'ID': u'AAA', u'subID': u'0'}     70.0                 1  
2  {u'ID': u'BBB', u'subID': u'0'}     50.0                 0
3  {u'ID': u'BBB', u'subID': u'0'}     20.0                 1
4  {u'ID': u'BBB', u'subID': u'1'}    200.0                 1
5                             None      NaN                 0
```

I tried with the following code :

```
df['isMinimalLatency'] = df['latency'].eq(df.groupby('ID')['latency'].min()).astype(int)
```

But I get the error :

```
File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1601, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_labels
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

How can I solve my problem ?

Notes :

- Data with `ID` at None are relevant and cannot be removed (because of other columns)
- Data with `ID` at None should always have `isMinimalLatency` at 0

Comment: You can't group on dictionaries as they are not hashable, maybe you can convert your id to something more solid first?

Comment: may be `df.groupby(df.ID.apply(lambda x: json.dumps(x)))['latency'].min()` after `import json` ?

Comment: As proposed by @ChristianSloper, I used something more solid by simply concatenating fields of my ID dict.
I was to focused on the 'None' case to see that the solution was in fact really simple. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It look like that data type of ID column is `dict` and `dict` can't be used with `groupby()`.
So how about create ID column of `str` type and processing DataFrame as following?

```
    df['strID'] = df['ID'].astype(str)  

    min_by_id = df.groupby('strID').min()['latency']  
    min_by_id = min_by_id.reset_index()  
    min_by_id.rename(columns={'latency':'min_latency'} , inplace=True)  

    df = pd.merge(df , min_by_id , on='strID' , how='left')  

    df['isMinimalLatency'] = 0  
    df['isMinimalLatency'] = df['isMinimalLatency'].where(df['latency'] != df['min_latency'] , 1)
    print(df)
```